# How to check if you are entering (at the moment) text in input field?

Tags: php, jquery

I have an input form for searching products in my website,and i have made an jquery on key up event to pass every letter in php.And php must check if there is a match in letters and display only those products that have those written letters in it.Like 4 weeks passed and i cannot create my instant search,lol.The problem this time is that i cannot create the php checking code,i have used                       Isset() and !empty() properties.(both didn't work as expected;/)

```
if(!empty($_POST["fsearch"])) {
    echo "True";
} else {
    echo "false";
}
```

And it is returning false,no matter is there anything typed in input field or not...I need event happen when typing,not after you typed the word and clicked enter.
There is code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
 $("#food_search").keyup(function(event) {
  var search_term =$(this).val();
  console.log(search_term);
        $.ajax({
         type:"POST",
         url:"/Food-Search",
         data:{fsearch:search_term},
         success:function(res) {
          $("#food_search_result").html(res);
          console.log(res);
         },
         error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
               alert(xhr.status);
               alert(xhr.responseText);
               alert(thrownError);
           }
       });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!----------------------------------------------------------------
                              HTML
----------------------------------------------------------------->
<form method="POST">
    <p>Търсене на храни: <input type="text" name="fsearch" id="food_search"></p>
</form>
<!----------------------------------------------------------------
                             PHP
----------------------------------------------------------------->
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['fsearch'])) {
    echo "True";
} else {
    echo "false";
}
?>
```

So how can I do it to work as expected.THANKS !

Comment: how does the response look like ? what is the console output? check the netweork tab, its easy to type faster than response so i recommend some throttle

Comment: There is no errors in console there is the result: http://prntscr.com/dwnwxc

Comment: 1. Go check via your browser’s developers tools (network panel) if the request sent is indeed a POST request, and contains the right data. 2. Use `var_dump($_POST)` in your PHP script to inspect what data was received.